# regex expression to match 5pt throught 30 pt

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm struggling to create a regex expresion in Javascript to match values between `5pt` and `30pt`.

That is `5pt`, `6pt`, `7pt`, ..., `29pt` and `30pt`. The value should have a number between `5` and `30` followed by `pt`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will match anything from 5-30 and *will not* match things like 35pt. So far in the above regexes provided, *only Andrew's method avoids false positives like matching "35pt" as "5pt"*.

```
var re = /(?:^|[^0-9])((?:30|[12][0-9]|[5-9])pt)/i
var text = "5pt 25pt 30pt 35pt";
while (result = re.exec(text)) {
  console.log(result[1]);
}
// returns 5pt, 14pt, 30pt
```

where your match is in the first backreference. Note the importance of screening for things like other numbers before.

If you're indifferent to false positives like that, try

```
/(?:30|[12][0-9]|[5-9])pt)/
```

where the entire match is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
/\b([5-9]|[1-2][0-9]|30)pt\b/
```

The 30 is the odd one out because 31 would be invalid.

***Edit:*** Added a boundary in there so it doesn't match things like '35pt'

Comment: This may be fine with the tester, but it also matches things like 35pt (the "5pt" part), 130pt, etc.

Comment: I could have also used lookaheads but I assume that this is in the context of CSS. If it is, than anything that could be valid to follow or precede the size is indeed a word boundary.

Comment: +1 You're probably right about it being CSS. This matches things like `"font-size:15pt;"`, in case anyone's worried about what constitutes a word boundary.

Answer (score 3):

Probably something like this:

```
([5-9]|[1-2][0-9]|30)pt
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
mystring.match(/([5-9]|30|[1-2][0-9])pt/);
```

Comment: That will also match 31pt to 39pt.

Comment: @Daniel -- heh. oops. fixed it.

Comment: it will also match 1pt to 4pt (instead of 5pt to 9pt)

Answer (score 2):

This one will include 5-30, but will not include 31-39.

```
mystring.match(/\b([5-9]|30|[1-2][0-9])pt/);
```

Comment: Erm, this matches "1pt", doesn't match "6pt", and matches things like "35pt" as "5pt".

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to match a string that contains for example `15pt` (nothing else), you can simply do:

```
function isStrBetween(s, min, max, postfix) {
    var regex=new RegExp('^[0-9]+'+postfix+'$');
    if (!regex.test(s)) {
        return false;             
    }
    var num=parseInt(s, 10);
    return (num >=min && num <=max);
}

var isBetweenLimits=isStrBetween('15pt', 5, 30, 'pt');
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3J58f/)

The function will return either `true` or `false`.